# PHP/MYSQL validate

Tags: php, mysql

just a simple question. How can I show 1 specific error from this?

```
$search_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$email'");
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($search_query);
if($num_row >= 1){
    $errors['username'] = "username is unavailable.";
    $errors['email'] = "Email address is unavailable.";
}else
{//insert.....
```

They both show the error, but not working with `$username`.

Just can't figure it out.

And if it's not asking too much, can you please add if the username/email is available?

Thanks in advance.

I'll put the `$errors` after the input tag:

```
                    <p>username:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){echo $_POST['username'];} ?>">
                    <?php if(isset($errors['username'])){echo "<h5>" .$errors['username']. "</h5>"; } ?></td>
            </tr>
                <td><p>email:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){echo $_POST['email'];} ?>">
                    <?php if(isset($errors['email'])){echo "<h5>" .$errors['email']. "</h5>"; } ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: umm... `echo $errors....`?

Comment: oops sorry @Fred-ii- ill edit it where i print my errors :)

Comment: any errors from error reporting? and look at your html source and check for errors on the query

Comment: Do you mean you want to know which column matched? e.g. what is `unavailable`.

Comment: Select your 2 columns and do a check in PHP, or you do do a case in mysql.

Comment: just do 2 queries instead of 1... you're welcome

Answer (score 3):

```
 mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());
```

like

```
$search_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And

```
  $num_row = mysql_num_rows($search_query)or die(mysql_error());
```